# Is there a way to tell flow to typecheck every file, not just the ones with /* flow */?

Tags: flowtype

In the official examples they always have `/* @flow */` at the top of the page. Now that's nice and helpful for an existing project, where I want to opt-in to flow for each file. Building a new project from scratch I would like to just have flow type checking everywhere, without having to type `/* @flow */` every time. Is it possible?

Comment: You can [**type check all files**](https://flowtype.org/docs/new-project.html#typechecking-your-files) with `flow check --all`.

Comment: this is the answer! Thanks, I should have known it would be in the docs.

Comment: No problem :) It is very easy to miss.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assuming you have a `.flowconfig` or you can make one, [you can add](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-all-boolean)

```
[options]
all=true
```

in there.

Note that this is literally *all* files, so that will also include random files in `node_modules`. Another alternative would be to use `@flow` and just use a lint rule like [`require-valid-file-annotation`](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-flowtype#require-valid-file-annotation) for ESLint.

Comment: This also checks all files in `node_modules/`, inevitably resulting in tons of errors...

Comment: @Hubro You can always ignore those files, but the question is "all files", so yep node_modules would be included. Flow has no way to know if you would want to ignore node_modules or not.

Comment: I'm guessing OP meant to say "every file **in my project**". Using `[ignore]` is not a valid solution as it disables type checking for all selected files, including those you import from your own source. [See related issue in official repository](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/284)

Comment: @Hubro I don't disagree, but I also don't get the downvote. The user never specified, so this is addressing what they want, and they accepted the answer. I general I think using `all=true` is a huge mistake. You should just have a lint rule that enforces the presence of `@flow` if you want it for just your own files.

Comment: I voted based on the way I understood the question. I suppose I could agree to remove the vote as the answer is *technically* correct (although not useful in my opinion) but I'm not allowed to remove it unless the answer is edited. Perhaps you could include in your answer the pitfalls of using `all=true`... :)